# VSTS linking *to* work items on the product backlog view in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, jira

In Jira you can simply copy the URL of a work item to link to it, send it to someone on slack or whatever. Super handy.

In VSTS it doesn't look like that's possible, the URL doesn't change based on the work item selected.

The best I could do was copy the little link on the top left which goes to the work items edit screen but what I'd really like is a link which goes to the work item popup with the sprint wall in the background

Comment: Don't think this is possible.

Comment: As jessehouwing said that it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the link to the work item by right-clicking, copy link location from just about any work item grid and board.

[image]
[image]

You can copy the work item link from the Edit view by right-clicking the `WORK ITEM TYPE #123` and selecting "copy link address"

[image]

There is no link which will directly open the backlog view or board view with the work item in edit mode.